# volley returns error response

Tags: android, android-volley

I have to make a json post request  with the following parameters.

```
{"method":"login","data":{"username":"korea","password":"123456"}}
```

I use volley to make post request and follwoing is my code to do post request.

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, loginURL, null,
                        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                                Toast.makeText(mContext,response.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }
                        },
                        new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                Log.e("Volley", "Error");

                            }
                        }
                ){
                    @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                        Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
                        map.put("method","login");
                        map.put("username","korea");
                        map.put("password","123456");
                        return map;
                    }
                };
                requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
                requestQueue.start();
```

Im getting error response from server. How to get proper response from server?

Comment: What error response is the server giving you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `Request.Method.GET` to `Request.Method.POST`. Then pass a JSONObject as the third parameter where you currently have `null`;

For example:

```
JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
data.put("username","korea");
data.put("password","123456");

JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
jsonObject.put("method","login");
jsonObject.put("data",data);

JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, loginURL, jsonObject, responseListener, errorListener);
```

Comment: I'm getting `com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 `

Comment: I think it means that the server is sending an empty response. You could test it with the Advanced Rest Client add-on for Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

> I use volley to make post request and follwoing is my code to do post request

That is not a `POST` request, AFAICT. You are using `Request.Method.GET`.

Answer (score 0):

Use following method to post the data to server

```
public void postDataVolley(Context context,String url,JSONObject sendObj){
    try {
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObj = new JsonObjectRequest(url,sendObj, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.d("Volley", "Volley JSON post" + response);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.d("Volley", "Volley JSON post" + "That didn't work!");
            }
        });

        queue.add(jsonObj);

    }catch(Exception e){

    }
}
```

Comment: it throws the following error `com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 `